# xslt color text output

Tags: xslt, text, colors, terminal

I'd like to output colored text to a linux terminal using XSLT on an nmap xml output.
I tried ANSI sequences (`\033[01;31m` for example to have bold red) with no success.

what would you suggest ?

here's output sample : https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html
I don't care too much about what part you choose to color, I need to know how to add color to any output (output being text in a terminal).

thanks.

Comment: Any input/output examples?

Comment: Which XSLT processor and XML parser do you use, does it support XML 1.1 where the ESC character is allowed as e.g. `&#x1B;`? I am not on LINUX but when I use Saxon 9 to have an XSLT stylesheet using XML 1.1 instead of 1.0 output e.g. `<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">&#x1B;[31mtest&#x1B;[0mtest</xsl:template>` and have that output as a text file, when I then output the text file in the console the first "test" word appears in red. It doesn't work however when the Saxon writes directly to the console, then I only get the output `[31mtest[0mtest`.

Comment: So the main approach seems to use XML 1.1 to be able to output the ESC control character where needed as `&#x1B;`, the rest of the control sequences like the e.g. `[31` shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: I'm using `Xalan-c` whose "supported specifications are defined by the W3C XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0 and the XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0 recommendations"

Comment: The version of XSLT is not relevant, if the XML parser used by Xalan-C supports XML version 1.1 you should be able to output the escape character.

Comment: what is the XML parser ? `nmap`'s output is in XML, and I simply pipe it to Xalan-C.

Comment: I think Xalan C uses Xerces C as the XML parser.

Comment: Try whether Xalan C allows you to use a stylesheet with XML version 1.1 e.g. `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"><xsl:output method="text"/><xsl:template match="/">&#x1B;[31mtest&#x1B;[0mtest</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`.

Comment: this seems to work : I get a red test and another regular one. How do I use it with a value-of select. I tried different things like adding it to xsl:text, or to concat(). EDIT: forgot to change xml declaration from 1.0 to 1.1. it works; thank you very much.